# Linking and controller function of directive which is represented as an attribute of another directive don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Have the following problem. I want to make two directives. One of them will be an attribute for another.
Something like this.

```
<html>
<title>Directives</title>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <outer inner></outer>
</body>
</html>
```

The directive source code is here:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('inner', function() {
    return {
        require: "^ngModel",
        restrict: "AC",
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: /* here is a path to template it's not interesting*/,
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('controller...');
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {         
            console.log('link...');
        }
    };
});


app.directive('outer', function($q, $rootScope) {   
    return {        
        require: "^ngModel",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: { /* isolated scope */ },
        controller: function($scope) {},
        templateUrl: /* path to template */,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {}
    }
});
```

The problem is that controller of outer works, but inner doesn't... Neither link nor controller function works... Can't understand what is wrong...

Any ideas?

Comment: That code is not enough I think. I have no problem running that. Try with a plunker to put enough code to make it break.

Comment: Indeed a fiddle/plunk, but can you also try without the `replace: true`?

Comment: Actually this is all I have... But here is the same code on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vz5Tt/5/. Maybe it will be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is because both directives have been asked to render a template on the same element, and its ambiguous as to which one should be given priority.

You can fix this by giving the inner directive priority over the outer directive (higher numbers indicate higher priority).

Inner:

```
app.directive('inner', function() {
   return {
       priority:2,
       restrict: "AC",
       transclude: true,
       replace: false,
       template: "<div>{{say()}}<span ng-transclude/></div>",
       controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "";

        $scope.say = function() {
            return "this is message";
        };

       // $scope.say(); // this doesn't work as well
        console.log('controller...');
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {    
          // alert('hey');
          // console.log('link...');
       }
    };
 });
```

Also, both directives cannot transclude their contents.  One must be 'transclude:false' and the other must be transclude:true.

```
app.directive('outer', function($q, $rootScope) {   

    return {       
        priority:1,
        restrict: "E",
        transclude:false,
        scope: { /* isolated scope */ },
        controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "";

        $scope.sayAgain = function() {
            return  "one more message";
        };

        $scope.sayAgain(); // this doesn't work as well
    },
    template: "<div>{{sayAgain()}}</div>",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {}
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vz5Tt/7/)